# Get data from 3rd table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

- wp_posts
- wp_metadata
- users

When I get my query from `wp_posts` I'm using `LEFT JOIN` to get the data from the `wp_metadata`, but how can I get a value from the 3rd table `users`?

Example:

I have one post on my WordPress blog. On that post I have some meta-fields - one of them is called `userid`. My users are located in a table outside of WordPress. How can I get the user's username from the table `users` where the post-meta-key `userid` is equal to the `users`-tables row ID?

Here is my SQL-request as it is right now:

```
$result = query("
SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt, post_content, 
       m.meta_value AS placeid, 
       i.meta_value AS photoid, 
       r.meta_value AS rating, 
       u.meta_value AS userid, 
       b.username 
FROM wp_posts p 
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (m.post_id = p.ID) 
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta i ON (i.post_id = p.ID) 
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta r ON (r.post_id = p.ID) 
       JOIN wp_postmeta u ON (u.post_id = p.ID) 
       LEFT JOIN brugere b ON (b.id = userid) 
WHERE m.meta_key = 'placeid' 
       AND i.meta_key = 'photoid' 
       AND r.meta_key = 'rating' 
       AND u.meta_key = 'userid' 
       AND post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 50
");
```

I want *one* query, because I'm using the query on a `print json_encode`.

Comment: This seems like a MySQL question rather than a WordPress question, and so it's probably [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context)").  You might be further ahead to ask it on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).

Comment: @PatJ It depends on the schema of the WordPress tables, so it is WordPress specific.

Comment: agree with @PatJ, this question requires SQL expertise. Doesn't look like understanding the DB schema is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your query, but wouldn't something like this accomplish it?

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
    ON p.ID = pm.post_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u
    ON pm.meta_value = u.user_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = 'user_id'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p.ID DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I think it works - the result shows. But how can I get u.username in the same query?

Comment: If you left the SELECT with a wildcard it should come through unless its conflicting with another username column. You're probably best off narrowing down the SELECT to only include fields you want including u.username